# Subtraction (beginner)

Tags: java, subtraction

```
public class Main {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (x < 5) {

        y = x - y;
        System.out.print(x + y);
        x = x + 1;
    }
}
}
```

When I calculate this math myself. I get these answers:

- y = 0 - 0 = 0
- y = 1 - 0 = 1
- y = 2 - 1 = 1
- y = 3 - 1 = 2
- y = 4 - 2 = 2

01122

But when I compile it. I get the answer

02356

I just don't get it. Could someone explain?

Comment: You print `x + y`, not just `y`. You're not taking this into account in your calculation by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing x+y not y

0+0=0 ; 1+1=2; 1+2=3; 2+3=5; 2+4=6

02356

Answer (score 0):

In first iteration x=0,y=0 so x-y = 0 = y and x+y=0 so `0` will be printed.
In 2nd iteration x=1,y=0 so x-y = 1 = y and x+y=2 so `2` will be printed.
thus x and y will be updated.

In your calculation, you are not updating `y`

Answer (score 0):

Use the debug, you will see that the iterations are correct because you are manipulating the x value after the x+y operation addition

[image]

Comment: You print x + y, not just y